# function to separate a string in c

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void separate(char s[20], char dummy[10], char* p){
    strcpy(dummy, s);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(dummy); i++){
        if (dummy[i] == ' '){
            dummy[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
    *p = strchr(s, ' ');
    p++;
}
int main(){
    char s[10];
    char dummy[10];
    char l;
    gets(s);

    separate(s, dummy, &l);
    puts(dummy);
    puts(l);
}
```

I'm having trouble passing the last name to the main function as a string, the goal is to separate a string that consists of someone's first and last name.

Comment: `gets(s);` <== don't do that. What if the user's name is e.g. `Yossef Nasr` ? Even such a relatively short name triggers a buffer overflow with your 10 character buffer. You could increase the buffer size to handle your own name, but no buffer size is actually safe. `gets` is hopelessly broken. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: Curios, why 20 in `separate(char s[20],...`, yet 10 in `char s[10]; ...    separate(s, dummy, &l);`?

Comment: `*p = strchr(s, ' ');` implies compiler warnings are not fully enabled as that should have generated a warning.  Save time.  Enable compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    void separate(char name[], char first[], char last[]){
    strcpy(first, name);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(first); i++){
        if (first[i] == ' '){
            first[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
    char *p = strchr(name, ' ');
    p++;
    strcpy(last, p);
}

int main(){
    char n[10], f[10], l[10];
    gets(n);
    separate(n, f, l);
    puts(f);
    puts(l);
}
```

I figured it out, thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Please don't use `gets`.

Comment: I know I shouldn't but it's for an assignment and I'm not allowed to use functions that weren't explained in my class.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `fgets`? Surely you are allowed to, I would be worried if they are making you use `gets` to read strings.

Comment: Nope I'm not allowed to

Comment: Things here in Egypt are pretty messed up, the university doesn't even pay for visual studio c++ they cracked it and it's the 2008 version.

Comment: @YossefNasr Hmmm, Unclear why crack a proprietary version of SW to teach folks who may want to earn a living programing when good free legitimate versions exist.  Example "gcc" which implements C11 is free at https://www.cygwin.com.  One learns many things while at the university, I guess.

Comment: This answer still suffers from memory mis-management.  Insufficient sized buffers, no overflow protection, reliance on a single space, no error handling for unexpected input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using `fgets`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 20
#define NAMESTRLEN 10

void separate(char buffer[], char firstname[], char lastname[]);

int
main(void) {
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE], firstname[NAMESTRLEN], lastname[NAMESTRLEN];
    size_t slen;

    printf("Enter first and last name: ");
    if (fgets(buffer, BUFFSIZE, stdin) == NULL) {
        printf("Error reading into buffer.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }  

    slen = strlen(buffer);
    if (slen > 0) {
        if (buffer[slen-1] == '\n') {
            buffer[slen-1] = '\0';
        } else {
            printf("Exceeded buffer length: %d.\n", BUFFSIZE);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    if (!*buffer) {
        printf("Nothing entered.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    separate(buffer, firstname, lastname);

    printf("Firstname = %s\n", firstname);
    printf("Lastname = %s\n", lastname);

    return 0;
}

void
separate(char buffer[], char firstname[], char lastname[]) {
    int i;
    char *last;
    const char sep = ' ';

    for (i = 0; buffer[i] != sep; i++) {
        firstname[i] = buffer[i];
    }
    firstname[i] = '\0';

    last = strchr(buffer, sep);
    last++;

    strcpy(lastname, last);
}
```